# Android plugin Jenkins. Error: "emulator" package must be installed! Jenkins docker

Tags: android, docker, jenkins

i have a problem with compiling a project. While trying to compile i got error:

```
Error: "emulator" package must be installed!
```

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z03L9.png)

Im using jenkins via docker image for simple installation, so there is no such a command like a sdkmanager for me.

Any idea how to solve it?
Is sdkmanager installed when i was installing android plugin? Or is there any paths for it to test env variables

Thanks you and i hope i will get some help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.